# is it possible to use ICollector<T> or IAsyncCollector<T> with blobs?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobs

**Is it possible to use IAsyncCollector / ICollector with a blob binding?**

Azure Storage Queues allows you to use `ICollector` and `IAsyncCollector` within an output binding like so:

```
public static class ICollectorExample
{
    [FunctionName("CopyQueueMessageICollector")]
    public static void Run(
        [QueueTrigger("myqueue-items-source-3")] string myQueueItem,
        [Queue("myqueue-items-destination")] ICollector<string> myDestinationQueue,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"C# function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        myDestinationQueue.Add($"Copy 1: {myQueueItem}");
        myDestinationQueue.Add($"Copy 2: {myQueueItem}");
    }
}
```

**Is this functionality available with Blobs?**

For example, how can we get this to work?

```
[Blob("myblob-items-destination")] IAsyncCollector<string> myDestinationBlob,
            ILogger log)
```

Answer (score 2):

Bunch of `IEnumerable<T>` are supported:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/35#issuecomment-135924199

See samples here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/master/test/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.EndToEndTests/BlobBindingEndToEndTests.cs#L394

Comment: very interesting, would love to see a usage example

Comment: also the first link shows examples on INPUT bindings to blobs not output

Comment: for output you can use CloudBlobContainer/CloudBlobDirectory. See first example here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f0b71c54-c92c-4180-9896-70a4d1209ca2/naming-blob-output?forum=AzureFunctions

Comment: that example is 2 years old, is there an update on it, or  is it still the best way?